# node -v and which node yield different versions - how to reconcile?

Tags: node.js, bash

I installed the Ember CLI on my machine but wasn't able to execute the `ember new` command because, apparently, my node modules aren't in my $PATH.

The problem is that I have `node` installed...somewhere...but I can only find an older version of `node` installed via `nvm`.

```
> node -v
v.9.3.0

> which node
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node
```

So I have a global installation of node, v.9.3.0, and I have no idea where (so that I can set my npm config correctly).

How do I consolidate my global node installations, and how?

The only relevant lines in my bash dotfiles:

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/myusername/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

There seems to be a node installation in `/usr/local/bin/` (about 22MB).

Comment: Run `type node`, to get the shell's own view of what it's doing. `which` -- as an external program that isn't part of the shell and can't see shell functions, shell aliases, cached PATH lookups, etc -- is frequently wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that yields `node is hashed (/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node)`

Comment: Does `/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node -v` yield the same output? If so, well, there's your answer. :)

Comment: it yields `v.9.3.0` lol. How did this happen?! I guess at least it's all in `nvm`'s hands

Comment: Is there a reason the lines activating your nvm installation are still uncommented in your dotfiles? If you don't want to use the nvm-installed `node`, easiest thing is to remove those lines and maybe even delete the directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i'll give that a shot! Thank you

Comment: np. Depending on the details of how your OS does session initialization, you may need to log out and back in to prevent environment variables from being inherited from a prior process in your login session. If `declare -p NVM_DIR` says that the variable isn't found, you can be comfortable that the shell you're in isn't inheriting settings created by the code above.